# Synergy only allows sharing in one direction

Tags: synergy

I have a unique issue that I need to illustrate with an image. See the following imgur link:

[image]

The mouse will pass one way but not the other. My second monitor is in Portrait mode.

Windows 10 64bit on both devices.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing in two directions is something we're working on in Synergy 2.0, which is coming soon! I'm on the Synergy development team at Symless.